# How to create table without migration in prisma?

Tags: node.js, prisma

How to create table without migration in prisma?

I used the sequelize library and there is method which create table without migration. (alter of model options)

I want to know the prisma has such method?

Comment: You can use this command: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate/db-push